# XCode 7.3 Simulator Unable to Boot

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So I've been working on a project at work for a while and have been having no issues running the app in the simulator. Yesterday, when I tried running the application again, the simulator opens and has a black screen. Then a popup appears stating "Unable to boot the simulator."

I did my research and I searched around and tried the following solutions to no avail:

- restarting Xcode,
- trying different applications in simulator
- deleting Xcode and redownloading
- restarting Mac
- deleting derived data
- tried different simulator devices

For reference, I am running Xcode 7.3 and running MacOSX 10.11.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to fix the problem by rebooting into recovery mode (hold command+r). Open terminal and run

`csrutil disable
reboot`

Went back into Xcode and ran the simulator.

Went back into revoery to enable what was disabled. Works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. It disappeared after installing the latest Sierra macOS.

Answer (score 0):

When the simulator starts
in the top menu click on Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings...

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything that this post and others suggest. 
Recovery mode 'csrutil' wasn't available for me, so I couldn't try that.

This is what had caused this issue in the first place, 
System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Apps downloaded from - This was set to 'Anywhere' changing this to 'Mac App Store and identified developers' fixed the issue for me.